# SDL_BlitSurface() 'dstrect' - Not working as I expected

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2, sdl-gfx

I am new to SDL but have used C++ a fair bit over the years. I'm struggling with displaying sprites with a scale. EG. Here I am trying to draw a grid of squares (ie. Tetris) but  the source BMP is 32x32 and I wish to display it at 16x16. The CELL_SIZE is const int =16;

It seems to me from looking at the function to the best of my ability that the `dstrect` parameter is for the location AND size. The location works (ie. the squares are drawn into the grid at the correct x,y but the width/height remains 32 for some reason.

```
void TetrisSDL::Update()
    {
        //draw filled squares:
        std::vector<SDL_Rect*> rects;
        for(unsigned int x=0; x<GRID_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            for(unsigned int y=0; y<GRID_HEIGHT; y++)
            {
                if(Grid[x + (y*GRID_WIDTH)]!=0)
                {
                    SDL_Rect* rect=new SDL_Rect();
                    rect->x=x*CELL_SIZE;
                    rect->y=y*CELL_SIZE;
                    rect->w=CELL_SIZE;
                    rect->h=CELL_SIZE;
                    rects.push_back(rect);
                }
            }    
        }
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<rects.size(); i++)
        {
            int blit = SDL_BlitSurface(BlockSprite, NULL, winSurface, rects[i]);
            printf("Drawing Rect (blit result=%d) %d / %d,%d,%d,%d '\n'", blit, i, rects[i]->x, rects[i]->y, rects[i]->w, rects[i]->h);
        }
        
    }
```

But my printf log at the end tells me that Rect[i].w and h is actually 32 (ie. the size of the source and NOT the CELL_SIZE)

Comment: According [to the doc](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface), you are getting the expected behaviour, _"Only the position is used in the dstrect (the width and height are ignored)."_

Comment: Thank you. I found out I should actually use BlitScaled() instead of BlitSurface()